# Barabási–Albert model in Python

Tags: python, random, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I am trying to generate a synthetic network using the [Barabási–Albert model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barab%C3%A1si%E2%80%93Albert_model).
I don't wish to use any "fixed" library function, because later I intend to modify the mathematical expressions involved.

The probability of attraction is: Π(ki) = ki / ∑j kj. The following code seems to work when m = 1:

```py
if random.uniform(0.0, 1.0) <= p and t not in neighbours_per_node[i]:
    currentDegree[t] += 1 
    currentDegree[i] += 1
```

My problem is generalizing the code above for larger values of m, where m is the number of links per each new node.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is to randomly generate a subset of `m` nodes, where each node has the desired (non-uniform) probability of being selected.

A neat way is to map the list of weights to a list of [samples from exponential distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Distribution_of_the_minimum_of_exponential_random_variables), and then choose the `m` lowest numbers. This can be done using the [random.expovariate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.expovariate) function. A node with weight `w_1` will be chosen instead of a node with weight `w_2` with probability `w_1 / (w_1 + w_2)`, as required.

This solution is known as "[Algorithm A-Res](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling#Algorithm_A-Res)" and is due to [Efraimidis and Spirakis](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002001900500298X).

```py
import random

def random_subset_with_weights(weights, m):
    mapped_weights = [
        (random.expovariate(w), i)
        for i, w in enumerate(weights)
    ]
    return { i for _, i in sorted(mapped_weights)[:m] }

def barabasi_albert(n, m):
    # initialise with a complete graph on m vertices
    neighbours = [ set(range(m)) - {i} for i in range(m) ]
    degrees = [ m-1 for i in range(m) ]

    for i in range(m, n):
        n_neighbours = random_subset_with_weights(degrees, m)

        # add node with back-edges
        neighbours.append(n_neighbours)
        degrees.append(m)

        # add forward-edges
        for j in n_neighbours:
            neighbours[j].add(i)
            degrees[j] += 1

    return neighbours
```

Example:

```py
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(barabasi_albert(30, 3))
[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 17},
 {0, 2, 3, 5, 8, 12, 15, 16, 17, 23},
 {0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 9, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 24, 26, 27},
 {0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 10, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 27},
 {0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 21},
 {0, 1, 4, 7, 9, 19, 29},
 {10, 18, 2, 3, 4},
 {0, 3, 5, 15, 23, 29},
 {0, 1, 4, 9, 11, 13, 21, 28},
 {8, 2, 26, 5},
 {21, 3, 4, 12, 6},
 {2, 4, 8, 12, 14, 15, 18, 25},
 {1, 10, 11, 14},
 {8, 16, 2, 4, 20},
 {2, 11, 12},
 {19, 1, 11, 7},
 {24, 1, 2, 13},
 {0, 1, 2},
 {2, 11, 6},
 {2, 5, 15},
 {29, 2, 3, 13, 22},
 {8, 10, 26, 4},
 {27, 2, 3, 20},
 {1, 3, 25, 7},
 {16, 2, 3},
 {3, 11, 23},
 {9, 2, 28, 21},
 {2, 3, 28, 22},
 {8, 26, 27},
 {20, 5, 7}]
```

To adapt the algorithm by changing the formula which computes the weights, simply compute the list of weights using your own formula, and use that instead of `degrees`.

The set comprehension `{ i for _, i in sorted(mapped_weights)[:m] }` returns a set of the indices of the `m` lowest numbers in `mapped_weights`. It takes O(n log n) time to sort the list; so the overall complexity of generating a graph on `n` vertices is O(n² log n).

If you are generating large graphs, it will be more efficient to use a priority queue, or the [quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) algorithm, for selecting the `m` lowest numbers; in that case the overall complexity will be O(n²).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have already implemented a far less sophisticated method and I got the following results: https://i.imgur.com/GlZVXf0.png .The green dots are the experimental results while the red dots are the theoretical. I am worried though, shouldn't the last parts of the two graphs (theoretical ad experimental) coincide with each other?Or is it just an issue of linear binning?

Comment: I don't know what that graph is showing, and you are asking me about a different algorithm which I haven't seen, so I can't help. Perhaps post it as a separate question?

Comment: The green dots depict the degree distribution Pk produced by the Barabasi-Albert model. Although I am new to this, it is supposed to be ~k^(-3) a relation which is depicted by the red dots. The two graphs coincide for smaller values of k, but there is a deviation for larger k. Maybe this is due to the linear binning explained here: http://networksciencebook.com/chapter/4#advanced-b  You are right that I should perhaps post this as a separate question

Answer (score 1):

Before using the `if t not in neighbors_per_node[i]:` condition use, `if t in neighbors_per_node[i]:`, re-use `random.uniform(0.0,1.0)` and draw a new probability until `t not in neighbors_per_node[i]`.

In case it is helpful, my code in C++ for this is:

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) { // m connections
    ini:
    prob_sorteio = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX;
    // ... code
    if(t already has the connection) { goto ini; }
}

// goto ini: return to calculate a new probability.
```